# Website testing for some percent of visitors

Tags: testing, a-b-testing

What's the name of website testing method when the new feature is shown only for some users (not for all), for instance 20%?
Are there some online services for that?
I know about A/B testing but I'm not sure that's what I need.

Comment: This is exactly A/B testing.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [Google's Content Experiments](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1745152?hl=en).

You're right, this is an A/B test, most specifically a content test in order to take conclusions on what is the highest converting page.

It's possible to send just a percentage of the traffic as you request and the results are all inside Google Analytics, so you can integrate with Goals and Conversion funnels. Besides, is inside a platform you most likely already know.

You have other tutorials available, like this one, for example: http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/google-analytics-ab-split-test-tutorial

or:

http://online-behavior.com/testing/content-experiments

You can read about experiments here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1745147?topic=1745207